# Node js: write zip file (stored in a variable as Buffer) in a new window

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know I have a very pretty buffer that , if written directly to a file, gives me an acceptable zip file:

```
fs.writeFile("acceptable.zip", prettyBuffer);
//file acceptable.zip is a valid zip file
```

how can I provide this very prettyBuffer as a download for the user?

I tried

```
var uriContent = "data:application/zip," + prettyBuffer);  
window.open(uriContent)
```

and

```
var uriContent = "data:application/octet-stream," + prettyBuffer);  
window.open(uriContent)
```

and at least 10 variations with different encodings and it still won't work!

edit:

Here's my code

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var zip = new AdmZip();  
zip.addFile("row0", new Buffer("hi"), "comment");  
var prettyBuffer = zip.toBuffer()
var uriContent = "data:application/zip;base64," + prettyBuffer.toString('base64');

var encodedUri = uriContent;  
var link = document.createElement("a");  
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);  
link.setAttribute("download", "acceptable.zip");  
link.click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode it in base64:

```
console.log('<a href="data:application/zip;base64,' + prettyBuffer.toString('base64') + '" download="acceptable.zip">');
```

`download` is a new attribute in [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

> This attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource. If the attribute has a value, the browser should interpret that as the default filename that the author recommends for use in labeling the resource in a local file system. There are no restrictions on allowed values, but you should consider that most file systems have limitations with regard to what punctuation is supported in file names, and browsers are likely to adjust file names accordingly.
>
> You can use this with **data:**, blob: and filesystem: URLs, to make it easy for users to download programmatically generated content.

If you use the `http` module, you must write the buffer to the response body. Use `response.write()`.

```
var http = require('http');

var prettyBuffer = ...;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.path == '/acceptable.zip') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
      'Content-Length': prettyBuffer.length,
      'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=acceptable.zip'
    });
    res.write(prettyBuffer);
    res.end();
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
  }
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Comment: Actually, I have checked the file and while the zip itself works, the files inside it are 'corrupted' or all 0x000.... I use adm-zip to compress them

Comment: When you use `fs.writeFile(prettyBuffer)` the files are not corrupted?

Comment: yes. exactly. they are not. I update my post with new information about it

Comment: (I can't edit my comment) but apparently adm-zip is sort of buggy. I ended up going with JsZip. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using WINDOW in NodeJS?

1) Try setting proper response header:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/zip'})
```

2) Then send you buffer:

```
response.end(buffer)
```

3) On client side use something like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="file_URL">Download file</a>
```

Comment: That is not a proper Content-Type. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type